# Having trouble creating a Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm using Requests and Beautiful Soup to pull some Wikipedia data and then I want to put that into a Pandas DataFrame (all one cell with column name of Column1). I'm getting this error when trying to call the dataframe:

*ValueError: DataFrame constructor not properly called!*

Does anyone have any suggestions? Here's my code:

```
import pandas as pd 
import requests
import bs4
result = requests.get("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_States")
#Put the data into BS
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(result.text,"lxml")
#select any soup element
soup.select('p')
#take the result from the list element
Results = soup.select('p')[2].getText()
#print to csv
df = pd.DataFrame(Results, columns=['Column1'])  
print(df)
```

Comment: Make `Results` a collection -> `df = pd.DataFrame([Results], columns=['Column1'])` ?

Comment: What information do you trying to get from that page?

Comment: What is the format of `Results`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Results is a text string:

```
In [36]: Results
Out[36]: "The United States of America (U.S.A. or USA), commonly known as the United States (U.S. or US) or America, is a country primarily located in North America. It consists of 50 states, a federal district, five major unincorporated territories, 326 Indian reservations, and some minor possessions.[g] At 3.8\xa0million square miles (9.8\xa0million square kilometers), it is the world's third- or fourth-largest country by total area.[c] It borders Canada to the north and Mexico to the south. With a population of more than 328.2 million people, it is the third most populous country in the world. The national capital is Washington, D.C., and the most populous city is New York City.\n"
```

to get that into the column you can use `io`

```
pd.DataFrame(io.StringIO(Results), columns=['Column1'])
```

or as Henry Ecker noted use `[]` around the Results

```
pd.DataFrame([Results], columns=['Column1'])
```

You now have index at 0 with Column1 having Results

```
    Column1
0  The United States of America (U.S.A. or USA), commonly known as the United States (U.S. or US) or America, is a country primarily located in North America. It consists of 50 states, a federal district, five major unincorporated territories, 326 Indian reservations, and some minor possessions.[g] At 3.8 million square miles (9.8 million square kilometers), it is the world's third- or fourth-largest country by total area.[c] It borders Canada to the north and Mexico to the south. With a population of more than 328.2 million people, it is the third most populous country in the world. The national capital is Washington, D.C., and the most populous city is New York City.\n
```